# Extract a rar file in a double quoted folder with python

Tags: python, directory, quotes, rar, appdata

Hi how i can add the double quotes to a folder ? with a initial " and a final " ?  in a python file without receiving errors ?

this is the bat file with quotes

```html
rar.exe x -o+ -p12345pass temp.rar "%Localappdata%\Temp\"
```

and this is the python file without quotes

```html
win32api.WinExec("cmd.exe /c rar.exe x -o+ -p12345pass temp.rar %Localappdata%\\Temp\\",0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using single quotes can help you too:

```
win32api.WinExec('cmd.exe /c rar.exe x -o+ -p12345pass temp.rar \"%Localappdata%\\Temp\\\"',0)
```

Comment: And probably you don't even need the `cmd.exe /c`. I believe it can be run just: `win32api.WinExec('rar.exe ...` or `os.system('rar.exe ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use one antislash before each quotes

```py
win32api.WinExec("cmd.exe /c rar.exe x -o+ -p12345pass temp.rar \"%Localappdata%\\Temp\\\"",0)
```